# Как заставить сайт "запомнить" себя, Rselenium

Tags: парсер, selenium, r

Пытаюсь по-быстренькому накидать робота,который автоматически заходил бы в аккаунт и собирал данные.
Проблема в том, что на сайте (вк) стоит двухфакторная аутентификация, которая каждый раз требует код (и убивает идею автоматизации).

Как заставить Rselenium сохранять данные/куки/whatever,чтобы, нажав на кнопку "запомнить меня", вк в будущем запоминал данные браузера и не выдавал проверку по коду.

Браузер любой, предпочтительно phantom

P.S.убрать двойную проверку не могу

P.P.S. через Api будет банально дольше

Comment: Интересно, а "запомнить меня" реализовывается на стороне сервера или клиента? Т.е. если сервера, то он должен например по отпечатку запомнить, а если на стороне клиента, то выслать куки, которые будут сохранены браузером и при последующем запросе отправлены

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю. Насколько я понимаю, на стороне сервера.
Тем не менее, у меня нет абсолютно никаких идей о том, как заставить Rselenium запомнить куки (и что именно запоминать!) и использовать их, а не открывать новый браузер каждый раз.

Comment: Посмотрите у драйвера методы `get_cookies()` и `add_cookie`, хоть это реализация для питона, но протокол селениума общий: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058521/5909792 (поиск по rselenium к этому привел, похоже его реализация на `r` не такая популярная)

Comment: В RSelenium такие методы тоже есть.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если данные хранятся в Cookie, то можно воспользоваться методами `RSelenium` `getAllCookies` для их сохранения и `addCookie` для их восстановления. Если же необходимые данные хранятся в local storage, то можно воспользоваться методом `executeScript` для получения содержимого объекта `window.localStorage`.

Comment: Так тоже получилось (но вышло даже круче)


Спасибо!